# Call an external Web Api REST endpoint using AWS Lambda invoked by a WorkMail event

Tags: amazon-s3, asp.net-web-api2, aws-lambda, amazon-workmail

We are using a number of AWS services and would like to implement WorkMail to manage email accounts and invoke various Web Api endpoints. My high-level requirements are below. Is this possible?

1. Create email addresses (user accounts) * Done
2. When email is received for an email address (or alias), copy the email, with attachments, to a S3 Bucket folder that is associated with that user account / email address (the  S3 folder name will be retrieved via an external rest endpoint)
   ex: https://54.166.***.***/api/accounts/getS3Folder/test@test.com
3. Trigger a Lambda action that calls an external Web Api REST endpoint that will process the saved email message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Lambda function to listen to incoming Amazon SES messages.

Then read the attachment info in the event object.
With that, you'll have what you need to send the attachment and other data that you need to a certain directory in an S3 bucket.

Then, have the S3 bucket call another Lambda function (which can then call your external API) when they receive that file created by the first function.

Let us know if you need more information.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. 

I'm currently triggering my lambda from a S3 put event. I was hoping to retrieve the email after it is saved to S3 and then get / save the attachments. Will this work? If so, do you have any examples of a similar approach (Preferably in .net)  If not, do you have any example code otherwise?

Comment: my knowledge is limited in this area. I think you have to save it to S3 yourself as SES and S3 each has its own uses and they are independent.

and no, I don't have any example code.